# Android Galaxy S4 Preview with Pink and Green lines

Tags: android, video, recording

all.
I am making a video recorder which works fine on other devices but Samsung GS4.
As you know, GS4 has full HD resolution which is 1920 * 1280.
When I take a video with back camera, I set recorder.setVideoSize(1920, 1280) and it records correctly.
However, if I take a video with front cam, it shows below view.

[image]

I mean, when I record it, I can see the recordign screen.
However, after recording is done and I play the video file, it is corrupted like this.
I think it has something to do with video the setVideoSize().
I tried every possible pair of with and height for resolution but to no avail.

GS4 spec says

Front camera    2 megapixels 1080p HD Video Recording @ 30fps Back-illuminated sensor

but I don't know what video size I have to set it to.
Can anyone give me a clue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The front facing camera records at a default of 1920x1080 (1080p). Though because of the orientation, it may be 1080x1920.